# python shallow copies can they be similar to deepcopies

Tags: python

I am playing about with shallow copies in python. I came across a gotcha that I was not expecting.

My assumption was that a shallow copy was a new instance of a class with references to the objects in the class. This behavior is shown below.

```
>>> a = { 'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': [[1,2],2,3,4,5,6] }
>>> c = copy.copy(a['c'])
>>> d = a['c']
>>> a['c'] is c
False
>>> a['c'][0] is c[0]
True
>>> a['c'] is d
True
>>> a['c'][0] is d[0]
True
```

What surprised me was the following. As the elements of the shallow copied list are references to the elements in the list from `a` I assumed when I changed the mutable 1st element it would also change in `a`.

```
>>> c[0] = [3,3]
>>> c
[[3, 3], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'c': [[1, 2], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'b': 2}
>>> a['c'][0] is c[0]
False
```

I see since the change the first element is no longer a reference of `a`.

#### My Question:

If I changed all elements in the list would it be similar to a deepcopy?

Comment: How come `a['c']` suddenly changed from `[1]` to `[1,2]`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you asking if `a = copy(b); for each attribute of a: set attribute to an entirely different object` would be "similar" to `a = deepcopy(b)`? And how do you define "similar"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As the elements of the shallow copied list are references to the elements in the list from 'a' I assumed when I changed the mutable 1st element it would also change in 'a'.

The 1st element of `c` is a list, which is mutable. So, if you actually *did* mutate it, the result would be visible in `a`. For example:

```
>>> a = { 'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': [[1],2,3,4,5,6] }
>>> c = copy.copy(a['c'])
>>> c[0].append(0)
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': [[1, 0], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

But you didn't mutate it; you just replaced it with a different value.

The fact that both the original value (`[1, 2]`) and the new one (`[3, 3]`) are mutable is irrelevant; you aren't mutating anything (except for `c`, of course… but `c` is, as you already know, a shallow copy of `a['c']`, not the same object).

So:

> If I changed all elements in the list would it be similar to a deepcopy?

No, on two counts. Changing shared elements means you're changing all references. *Replacing* all elements of the list would be "similar to a deepcopy"… but not *the same*, unless you replaced them with `deepcopy`-like copies of the originals. If you replace them with shallow copies, you only push the exact same issue one level down. For example:

```
>>> a = [[[0]]]
>>> b = copy.copy(a[0])
>>> b[0] = copy.copy(b[0])
>>> a[0] is b
False
>>> a[0][0] is b[0]
False
>>> a[0][0][0] is b[0][0]
True
```

(In your example, you're replacing them with entirely different and unrelated values, which isn't really like a copy at all… but I think I know what you meant.)

Comment: thanks for clearing that up and yes I did mean mutable. woops

Comment: @MWright: OK, obviously you understood the words and that was just a minor typo, let me edit the answer to take that part out.

Comment: @MWright: BTW, when thinking this stuff through for myself in complicated cases, I find it helps me to avoid words that can be misleading. If I can't use the word "change", and have to explicitly say "mutate" or "rebind", and can't say "variable", and have to explicitly say "value" or "name", and so on, then… well, I can still confuse myself, but I can't mislead myself into thinking I'm not confused. If that makes any sense.

Comment: at first read you confused me with the above, but yes I need to take more care with my word choice. It is misleading to me and others. When I said 'similar' I meant to say the elements of the list were new instances. Thanks

Comment: @MWright: Right, it's similar to `deepcopy` in that they're new instances, but different in that those new instances are not deep copies of the originals, which is… pretty hard to explain, so apologies for the confusion.